# How to asign the points below a line to a specific value?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}...}`. I want to create a list `{{x1,z1,0},{x2,z2,0}...}` with $z1<y1, z2<y2\cdots$, so that I could `ListDensityPlot` the region below the line. How to achieve this? Here is my attempt:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Sqrt[1 - x];
ls = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];(*creating the original list*)
ListLinePlot[ls]
lsNew = Table[{#[[1]], y, 0}, {y, 0, #[[2]], 0.01}] &@ls 
(*Above line is problematic, however I want to achieve something like this*)
ListDensityPlot[lsNew]
```

Please start from `List` `ls`, I don't want to use an interpolation or the function I gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code, but with a slight modification (using `/@` instead of `@`, because the pure function you created isn't inherently listable)

```
lsNew = Table[{#[[1]], y, 0}, {y, 0, #[[2]], 0.01}] & /@ ls

ListDensityPlot[Flatten[lsNew, 1]]
```

[image]

The problem was that you can either do a `ListDensityPlot` on a rectangular array, or on a list of triples.  You had a triangular array of triples, so you just need to flatten it by one level.

Another way to get this would be to just use `Filling` on a `ListLinePlot`,

```
ListLinePlot[ls, Filling -> 0, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Darker[Blue], EdgeForm[None]]]
```

[image]

Interestingly, if you take the list you made and add in all the points above the line and set them equal to 1, it doesn't look nearly as good.

```
lsNew2 = Array[{ls[[#1, 1]], ls[[#2, 1]], 
      Boole[ls[[#2, 1]] >= ls[[#1, 2]]]} &, {Length@ls, Length@ls}]~
   Flatten~1;
ListDensityPlot[lsNew2],
```

[image]

Comment: Have you done other corrections? There are errors on my computer saying:`"Table::iterb: "Iterator {y,0,{0.01`,0.99498743710662`},0.01`} does not have appropriate bounds."@p"` .

Comment: D'oh! I did, sorry, will put up

Comment: Also, @buzhidao, wearing that hat makes it look like Bruce Lee playing Bane

Comment: Thanks for providing so many solutions! The first is want I really looking for! By the way, I thought it was a mask rather than a hat, so I put it on the mouth...

Comment: You're right, it's definitely a Darth Vader mask (but the site is calling all of them Hats), but shrunk down like that it looks like Bane's breathing mask.

Comment: But how do I know if my pure function is listable or not?

Comment: I just assume they aren't, and don't try to make them so.  Whenever you want to apply a function, say `f`, to a list, say `ls`, I just use `f /@ ls`.  Some built in functions are listable, and so you only have to do `f[ls]` or `f @ ls`, but I just like to use the `/@` notation.

Comment: OK, thanks! Seems that `/@` has a wider application than `@`

Comment: @JasonB  Pure functions are automatically listable when written in shortform and don't include any built in functions that are not listable. e.g. `#^2&` is listable, `If[# < 3, #^2, #]&` is not. To make a pure function listable: `Function[x, If[x < 3, x^2, x], Listable]`